# How to write '=' in a cell of a worksheet using openpyxl (or any other module) in python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have tried this following piece of code.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = '='

wb.save(r'C:\temp\new_book.xlsx')
```

When I check in the excel sheet, I see a nothing in the the (1,1) cell. I have tried the following lines of code to write '=' without any success.

1 ->

```
ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = r'='
```

2 ->

```
a2 = ws['A2']
a2.number_format = 'Text'
ws.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value = '='
```

3 ->

```
ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = chr(61)
```

None of these option seem to store the value '=' in the A1 cell. It would be great if someone knows how to get this done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works just fine in openpyxl.

Comment: May I know which version of excel are you using? I have Excel 2013 installed, is there any property that needs to be changed? (My openpyxl version is 2.0.2)

Comment: Works just fine with openpyxl v2.3.5. If I open the file in either Excel 2010 or 2016, there is an `=` in cell A1

Comment: Your second Example is wrong. **'A2'** should read `ws.cell(row = 2, column = 1).value = '=`, please edit.

Comment: Thanks for all the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your three Examples are working for me.

Beside this your openpyxl version is outdated, update to at least **2.4.x**.

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***